# Modify Linq query to support optional relationships

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem with a linq query where a joining record is null.

I have 3 models:

Location, Company, and Person.

- A Person must be at a single company
- A Person may have a single Location
- A Company may have multiple People

I'm using the following LINQ query to retrieve a distinct list of all the locations for all of the people at a specific company:

```
locations =
            db.Companies.Where(c => c.Name == company.Name)
            .SelectMany(c => c.People)
            .Select(p => p.Location)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```

The problem arises where a Peron that is retrieved from this query does not have a Location (a Location is optional for a Person).

In this situation, the following query, which gets the name of each location, fails due to Object reference not set to an object:

```
locations.Select(g => g.Name).ToList()
```

How can I change the above line to ignore records where a retreived Person record does not have a location?

Comment: When you say that a Person doesn't have a location, do you mean that the property is null, or an empty string ?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified - Null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
locations =
            db.Companies.Where(c => c.Name == company.Name)
            .SelectMany(c => c.People)
            .Where(p => p.Location !=null)
            .Select(p => p.Location)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Commonly, you can use the null coalescing or conditional operators to check for the null, and then substitute it with a suitable default, e.g.:

```
locations =
        db.Companies.Where(c => c.Name == company.Name)
        .SelectMany(c => c.People)
        .Select(p => p.Location ?? SomeDefaultLocation)
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();
```

e.g. `SomeDefaultLocation` could be a `readonly static` instance of `Location`.

However, in the context you provided, this doesn't really make sense (e.g. all persons with no location will just return `SomeDefaultLocation`). This would be a more typical usage:

```
personAndLocations =
        db.Companies.Where(c => c.Name == company.Name)
        .SelectMany(c => c.People)
        .Select(p => new 
          {Person = p, 
           Location = p.Location ?? SomeDefaultLocation})
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the use of the null coalescing operator, great example, although I've marked @Luc Morins as the answer as it better fit my reqs